# Proper way of applying custom CSS to TinyMCE editor

Tags: css, tinymce

I integrated a TinyMCE ver 4.9.9 instance to my textarea of ID `#mytextarea`. It is being applied and here's the screenshot given by:

[image]

The code used to initialize the editor is:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#mytextarea",
    height: 300,
    statusbar: false,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: "link lists placeholder",
    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic underline | bullist numlist | link"
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
    <table align="center" border="0" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="mytextarea">Content:</label></th>
            <td><textarea name="mytextarea" id="mytextarea"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Now I want to change the appearance of this editor e.g. remove box-shadow and applying border color of my own choice so that it can blend with my site's theme and color scheme.

I don't know exactly how to do it property according to their official docs. To achieve my requirements, I added `content_css: "css/style.css"` to `tinymce.init({...});`. My code becomes:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#mytextarea",
    height: 300,
    statusbar: false,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: "link lists placeholder",
    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic underline | bullist numlist | link",
    content_css: "css/style.css"
});
```

But I don't know what to do in my `style.css`. Whether should I have to apply my custom CSS to TinyMCE editor classes like this

```
.mce-tinymce {
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

But even after applying above, nothing happened. The `box-shadow` didn't remove from editor.

So I went to my main file in which I wrote TinyMCE code above and wrote my custom CSS as:

```
<style type="text/css">
.mce-tinymce {
    box-shadow:none !important;
}
</style>
```

and it did work for me.

You can see the `box-shadow` is gone away now.

[image]

So can anyone please suggest me what is proper and accurate way of applying custom CSS to TinyMCE editor instance? Is my second approach right or wrong? If it is wrong then how to catch editor's classes, apply our own CSS and where to write them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer your question we first need to know how TinyMCE itself gets rendered to the page and what `content_css` actually impacts.

If you use your browser's dev tools to inspect the page after TinyMCE appears you will see that TinyMCE renders itself as a series of `div` elements and a single `iframe`.

The `menubar`, `toolbar(s)`, and `statusbar` are all rendered as a nested group of `div` elements on the page where you invoke TinyMCE.  The rectangle where you actually type in content is an `iframe`.

If you want to inject CSS into the `iframe` so that it impacts the content you see in TinyMCE you need to use the `content_css` setting.  This injects the CSS you provide into the `iframe`.

By default, the look and feel of the editor itself (e.g. `menubar`, `toolbar(s)`, and `statusbar`) is handled by the TinyMCE skin.  If you want to impact the look and feel of the editor's  `menubar`, `toolbar(s)`, and `statusbar` you can either (a) modify your skin's `skin.css` file or (b) do what you did and add your own CSS to the main page to override the settings in `skin.css`.  Neither is right or wrong and they both will get to the end result you want to accomplish.

Comment: You have explained very well here and properly addressed my question. Thanks for that. So the conclusion here is that there is nothing right or wrong in changing the CSS the way I am doing.

Comment: But a very weird issue I see is that when I am applying the CSS rules in style.css and refer them with option `content_css: "css/style.css"`, they are not reflecting to the TinyMCE editor. But the same css when I put in the main page, they are applied. Strange! For example, `#txtcontent .mce-container {box-shadow:none !important;}` doesn't work by `content_css`.

Comment: However, when I change css for the content which goes into editor itself e.g.`body {color:blue;}`, the text color of editor's content becomes blue. How is it possible that the rules to change the look and feel of editor don't work through `content_css` but the rules to change the editor's content style do work?

Comment: As I said in the explanation, `content_css` impacts what is inside the iframe.  The skin's CSS handles the look and feel of the menubar, toolbar(s), statusbar, and the general look of the editor.  Your example is addressed in the skin not the iframe's content so it is handled in the skin's CSS not `content_css`.

Comment: Oh OK sorry, so I should continue the way what I am doing till now.

Comment: Either that or update the skin's CSS file - either is fine.  If this is resolved now can you mark this answer as correct so others don't spend time trying to solve the issue?